# Convert "Spring Data JPA" Method Query to JPQL Query

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm having a "Spring Data JPA" query that I find ugly because of the fact that I need to pass in multiple times the same userId.

My query is:

```
Page<CompanyEntity> findByClients_User_IdOrOwners_User_IdOrRelations_User_IdOrProjectManagers_User_IdOrSpecialists_User_Id(Long userId1, Long userId2, Long userId3, Long userId4, Long userId5, Pageable page);
```

As Suggested I should rewrite this query to use JPQL.

But I'm stuck on how I get the user object out of the collections

EDIT:

```
@Query("SELECT company FROM CompanyEntity company JOIN company.owners owners JOIN company.clients clients JOIN company.projectManagers managers JOIN company.specialists specialists JOIN company.relations relations")
```

Comment: Use an `@Query` annotation to manually define the query.

Comment: I have edited my post I'm trying but I don't see how I can get the owners user object because owners is a list

Comment: FYI That is not a "JPA method query", it is actually nothing at all to do with the JPA API. It is "Spring Data JPA", totally different API

Answer (score 1):

```
@Query("SELECT company FROM CompanyEntity company JOIN company.owners owners JOIN company.clients clients WHERE :userId IN owners.id OR :userId IN clients.id")
Page<CompanyEntity> find(@param("userId") Long userId, Pageable pageable)
```

(and so on for the other associations) should do the trick.

Comment: but the thing is that in the owners there is a UserEntity object so I also need that information because it's the id of the UserEntity I need to match. Should I do a left join then to fetch all the user entities?